# Converting a list of strings to a list of floats and getting the sum of all values

Tags: python

I have the following list in python 3.

```
['12 32.12 453\n', '54 123 65\n', '12 32\n', '12 32 54 765 876\n']
```

How do I remove the \n from the end of each entry? And how do I convert the list to

```
[12.0, 32.12, 453.0, 54.0, 123.0, 65.0, 12.0, 32.0, 12.0, 32.0, 54.0, 765.0, 876.0]
```

?

I need a way to convert each number to a float and add them all together to get a sum. this This is my code so far:

```
def calc_sum(filename):
    new_list = []
    try:
        file = open(filename)
    except:
        print("oops")
        return None
    line = file.readlines()
    print(line)
```

Comment: Use `s.split()` to get a list of strings that were separated by whitespace, for instance `'12 32.12 453\n'.split() -> ['12', 32.12', '453']`. Use e.g. `float('12')` to convert a string into a float.

Answer (score 1):

Convert to a list of floats:

```
>>> a = ['12 32.12 453\n', '54 123 65\n', '12 32\n', '12 32 54 765 876\n']    
>>> k = [float(y) for lst in (x.split() for x in a) for y in lst]
>>> k
[12.0, 32.12, 453.0, 54.0, 123.0, 65.0, 12.0, 32.0, 12.0, 32.0, 54.0, 765.0, 876.0]
```

Get the sum:

```
>>> sum(k)
2522.12
```

All in one line:

```
>>> sum(float(y) for lst in (x.split() for x in a) for y in lst)
2522.12
```

**Explanation**:

To see what's going on, here's equivalent code without the use of list/generator comprehensions:

```
k = []
for x in a:
    x = x.split()
    k.append(x)
```

`k` is now `[['12', '32.12', '453'], ['54', '123', '65'], ['12', '32'], ['12', '32', '54', '765', '876']]`. We've got rid of the newline characters and have a list of lists, each inner list containing strings (which can be converted to floating point numbers). Next, we flatten the list:

```
m = []
for sublist in k:
    for x in sublist:
        m.append(x)
```

`m` is `['12', '32.12', '453', '54', '123', '65', '12', '32', '12', '32', '54', '765', '876']`. Finally, we convert all string values to floats:

```
k = []
for x in m:
    k.append(float(x))
```

`k` is `[12.0, 32.12, 453.0, 54.0, 123.0, 65.0, 12.0, 32.0, 12.0, 32.0, 54.0, 765.0, 876.0]` and `sum(k)` will yield the sum over all the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `map`:

```
>>> x = ['12 32.12 453\n', '54 123 65\n', '12 32\n', '12 32 54 765 876\n']
>>> map(float, ''.join(x).split())
[12.0, 32.12, 453.0, 54.0, 123.0, 65.0, 12.0, 32.0, 12.0, 32.0, 54.0, 765.0, 876.0]
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

The `strip` method will remove trailing characters and the `split` method will split each line at spaces. Then use `float` to convert each chunk from string to float and `sum` to get a sum. Iterate over lines, sum line partials and you are done.

```
def calc_sum(filename)
    result = 0.0

    with open(filename) as stream:
        for line in stream:
            values = line.strip("\n").split(" ")
            result += sum(float(x) for x in values)

    return result
```